# inno setup exec appref-ms

Tags: exec, inno-setup, clickonce

I need from Inno Setup to run another application which is a clickonce application.

I tried to run the **appref-ms** file with the `exec()` function but it exits with:

> code 193 (not a valid Windows application).

How can I run **appref-ms** files from Inno Setup?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ShellExec()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) instead of [`Exec()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) works!